# Sticky footer on dynamic page - IE6 issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, sticky-footer

I have a page that has a sticky footer using this method:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

The page is being created dynamically through Javascript, all the browsers are working perfectly with my sticky footer except IE6 (unfortunately I have to support this dumb browser). The footer goes to the bottom of the window and stays there (the page extends way past the window size), so when you scroll the footer stays in the center.

Here is the relevant html code for my sticky footer:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">...</div>
  <div class="navigation">...</div>
  <div class="main">...</div>
  <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
.container { min-height:100%; position:relative; }
.main { padding-bottom:50px; }
.footer { padding:10px 0; position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; background:#ffffff; height:22px; line-height:22px; }
.ie6 .container { height:100%; zoom:1;}
```

Comment: Why you support IE6? That browser died.

Comment: it's unfortunate but the big enterprises are still too lazy to upgrade so I'm forced to support this embarrassment of a browser

Answer (score 0):

I always use the same method for my Sticky Footers and it also works for me in IE6, you should try it:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Good luck!